# How to group nesting of different SCSS classes

Tags: css, sass

This one works fine, but I need to set different styles for the elements:

```
&__open, &__content {
        height: 159.5px;
    }
```

But this one, which I tried, doesn't work:

```
&__open {
        height: 159.5px;

    + &__content {
        max-height: 100%;
    }
    }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? What final CSS should be?

Comment: @Justinas I use JS to add the "show" class to a block.
And so when the "show" class is added -> also at the same time the styles for the "content" class are added.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to have a nested &__ you can use:

```css
$parent: &;
&__open {
   height: 159.5px;

   &#{$parent}__content {
       max-height: 100%;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**suppose your parent class is "container"**
I am assuming your html to be like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="open"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

so : when you do this ,

```
&__open, &__content {
        height: 159.5px;
    }
```

here , &(ampersand) refers to parent(i.e "container" in this case);
so it is then converted to ,

```
.container__open, .container__content {
        height: 159.5px;
    }
```

by scss ,
But , when you do this ,

```
&__open {                // here & is "container" ( .container__open)
        height: 159.5px;

    + &__content {       // here & refers to container__open , which causes unexpected result  (.container__open__content)
        max-height: 100%;
    }
 }
```

**So the solution which I think will work is :**

```
&__open {              
        height: 159.5px;
}
 &__content {       
        max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that in my situation, the issue can only be solved by adding additional classes via JS.

Comment: This new edit should resolve your issue . Have a look at it once .